# Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview running alongside with Visual Studio 2010 SP1?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I would like to try out the new features in VS 11 Developer Preview on the machine that i do programming on with VS 2010 SP1. Is there a way I can install VS 11 Developer Preview without it affecting my current VS2010 SP1 instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install them side-by-side.  MSDN provides the caveats.  This has been true since the first version of VS.NET, and per the article linked to below, it still applies with the Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: My experience has been that the Preview did not work with my Web project (failed to open after converting solution) and that it (or .Net 4.5) caused at least 2 errors in our MSBuild script (despite targeting .Net 4 and using 2010 for all dev). On uninstalling .Net 4.5 and the VS Preview I had to reinstall VS2010 (errored on launch) and IIS7.5 (some missing handlers) to get back a working copy of each. Next time I'll use a virtual box :)

Comment: @Skym - Probably a good idea!  Particularly with pre-release software, but also not a bad idea when upgrading "relase" software to test it out first.

Answer (score 3):

I used Virtual Box.  It provides a clean environment that can't interfere with your production system, without requiring a separate computer.

Comment: +1.  I wanted to test all of the features of Windows 8 as well as trying out VS2011.    I ended up creating an empty partition and installing there, because I had issues with VirtualBox.  I'm sure the isues were something I did wrong, but +1 for suggesting running in a "clean" environment.